# Is there a way to handle password changes smoothly in a CALDAV scenario without locking accounts?

Tags: authentication, webdav, caldav

i have a scenario running with an own CALDAV-server and CALDAV-clients like (iOS-calendar, mac-Calendar, Android sync adapter, Thunderbird/Lightning, Outlook Sync, ...)

The authentication so far works via basic auth (https and the "Authentication"-Header).
The CALDAV-clients store the user/password in their configuration.

So far so good, but the issue comes now once the password of the user/account either gets changed, reset, expired, etc.
The server has a restrictive password policy enforced, which locks the account after x failed attempts (e.g. 10).

What is happening now obviously is, that once the CALDAV-client configuration was not updated it continues to use an old password.

The server responds with an 401 not authorized - ok, thats fine apparently again.

But the Clients still continue to use the outdated password. It would be nicer to stop polling and present the user with a dialog that his credentials are not valid anymore. But the clients are out of my control so nothing can be directly done here.

The result: after 2-3 iterations (as most clients tries multiple request in one sync iteration) the account on the server of the user is locked due to too many failed login attempts.

That is not nice. The issue seems to be generic and known as "stale passwords".
A solution could only be a better client handling (out of scope here) or a oAuth-token handling. But i was not able to find anything that standard CALDAV-clients supports this. Only google calendar seems to enforce an oAuth2 authorization before allowing CALDAV communication.

**So the question is, is there a good way to improve the bad experience of locked accounts?
Some special 401 response which tells the clients to forget the password or not using it again?**

constructive feedback highly welcome.

Edit:
for macOS and ios calendar i found a strange behavior (bug) causing and/or enforcing the described situation.
A standard 401 response will cause the clients to bring up the password dialog as expected and described above. The clients stop polling until a new password is entered - as desired.
In my case the 401 response body contained an inline base 64 image (img src="data..."):
This doesnt lead to a password renewal dialog! Just a "something goes wrong" error state.
The clients are continuing to poll! Locking the accounts after some tries ;(
A solution for this problem than will be to remove the inline image but for me it sounds like a bug that an inline image in the 401 response provokes a different behavior on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some special 401 response which tells the clients to forget the password or not using it again?

Well, 401 is that response. If the client receives a 401 it knows the the login/password combination it provided doesn't work anymore, and shouldn't retry with the same. Obviously the clients don't do this, partially because:

On the other side your servers x-failed-attempts locking doesn't work with stateless protocols for obvious reasons. HTTP doesn't have that feature builtin. Locking the account is a side effect a client doesn't have to expect when running idempotent HTTP requests.

Assume the client is downloading 10 batches of items concurrently. If the credentials invalidate during this, the account would immediately be locked :-)

*Summary*: You can't use basic auth naively with backends that lock accounts after n-tries.

Google and iCloud both use token based auth schemes (Google OAuth, iCloud a proprietary one). You can't expect those to work in other clients. E.g. while the Apple clients support OAuth for Google, I don't think they support that for other account types.

*So what can you do*

I'm reading your question so that you own the account server and that the account locking is intentional and desired. (I.e. it is not a side effect of a different (e.g. SSO) backend system you reach out to.)
I think in this case it should be reasonable to rework your account system to allow unlimited login attempts with just the old password.
The lock-after-n-attempts measure is to protect against people trying *different* passwords. In your case it is always the same and as a bonus it also matches the old password.
There are a lot of different variations of this approach.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately i don't own the account server - my caldav server sits as an application service on top of some infrastructure with the account server build-in. But i will try to forward this reasonable approach :/

Comment: "Sitting on top" - does that mean you see the authentication before passing it on? If so, you can implement almost the same thing in your layer. If a login attempt failed, cache a hash of the specific combination. If you see another attempt with the same, just return 401 w/o consulting the backend.

Comment: good point! - this was also an idea already evaluated - my infrastructure doesn't pass the authorization header to me - it explicitly empties it. ;(

Comment: i think i found a bug which has caused the described behavior of locked accounts.
Once a "normal" 401 response is coming the macOS and probably iOS calendar stops polling and wants to have a new password (dialog pops up). 
Once a 401 response comes which has an inline base 64 image as part of the response body the macOS calendar doesnt bringt up the new password dialog but just tells that something has gone wrong and continues polling with the assigned schedule. This enforces the issue of locked accounts. Sounds like a bug misbehavior on Apple side to me.

Comment: Rejecting a 401 w/ content could be a bug in the client: http://radar.apple.com. However the bigger bug seems to be in your code. A client can target and retry the server with a non-idempotent request as often as it likes. You just have to deal with it.